# how to separate leading words before first number in list in R

Tags: r, extract, tidyr, stringr

---

My list is:

```
   A      B
1 Alex    but            
2 likes   lala 54 hi     
3 a lot   number and 33 hello
4 of      face soap 34 hello  
5 food    35 hello
```

I would like to extract the string of words before the first number in column B and make it into a new column, column C. My desired output is:

```
   A        B                        C 
1 Alex      but                   
2 likes     lala 54 hi               lala
3 a lot     number and 33 hello      number and
4 of        face soap 34 hello       face soap
5 food      35 hello
```

Comment: FYI, the expectation that both the first and last rows produce an empty string makes this as a regular expression rather difficult. That is, it's easy enough to say "give me all characters before a number", which will produce the last row, but for the first row you are saying "give me something before a number unless there is no number then give me an empty string", which is a significant special case. In that case, I think @A.Suliman's production of `NA` (first row) is not inappropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Using positive look-ahead we can look for a text followed by a space and digit, then return this text using `stringr::str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
libary(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(C= str_extract(B,'\\D+(?= \\d+)'))


     A                   B          C
1  Alex                 but       <NA>
2 likes          lala 54 hi       lala
3 a lot number and 33 hello number and
4    of  face soap 34 hello  face soap
5  food            35 hello       <NA>
```

For more details about stringr and positive look-ahead you can check [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html)

Comment: This is producing `NA` instead of empty strings. This is easy enough to fix, but it would be good to expand this answer to include text on why you think `NA` is okay, and (if the OP desires) the way to get what is actually shown in the desired output (i.e., empty strings).

Comment: Add to your `mutate` call: `C = if_else(is.na(C), "", C)` to get the desired output.

Comment: I prefer empty strings because this is part of a larger project but yes replacing the NA to empty strings is not that difficult. This is a really great answer and I'll leave this question for a little bit to see if someone has another unique way.

Comment: @RamshaPerwez yes exactly If you prefer an empty string then you can fellow r2evans suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to attack this problem is by using the `dplyr` and `stringr` functions, which come with the `tidyverse` package.  Here is the code to solve your problem:

```
# install.packages('tidyverse')
library(tidyverse)

d <- tibble(A = c('Alex', 'likes', 'a lot', 'of', 'food'),
             B = c('but', 'lala 54 hi', 'number and 33 hello', 'face soap 34 hello', '35 hello'))

d %>% 
  mutate(C = str_extract(B, '\\D*(?=\\d)'))
```

Here is what you need to know about how this works:

`dplyr::mutate` creates a new column, C.  The data that it puts in this column is created by EXTRACTING (using `stringr::str_extract`) characters from column B.  The data that it extracts is pulled using a regular expression.

The regular expression used here is `\\D*(?=\\d)`.  That's complicated and gross looking, but what it is doing is saying "look for any non-numerical characters of any length that preceed a number.  Give me those characters, but not the numbers".

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps. Using `sapply` you apply the `gsub` function in a vectorized way through the values in column B and output a filtered vector.

```
new_column = sapply(df$B, function(x){gsub("^(.*?)[0-9].*", "\\1", x)})
```

This will give you a vector with the filtered values in column B.
Then you just add this new vector as a new column in your dataframe:

```
df$C= new_column
```

Comment: No need to use `sapply`, both `sub` and `gsub` are naturally vectorized. Try `gsub("^(.*?)[0-9].*", "\\1", df$B)`. (Unfortunately, your code does not produce the desired output.)

Comment: hi, this is a great answer! This works except for the first row. B1  does not have a number so it should not have copied onto C1. Is there any way to account for that problem as well?

Comment: @r2evans your modification is showing the same results as the above code. :(

Comment: I know, that's why I said "unfortunately". My comment was about the unnecessary use of `sapply`, not about the correct operation of `gsub`. Perhaps I should have said "*Unfortunately, the pattern does not produce the desired output*".

Comment: Thanks for that @r2evans and indeed I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, in base R.

```
df <- data.frame(A=c("Alex", "likes", "a lot", "of", "food"), B=c("but", "lala 54 hi", "number and 33 hello", "face soap 34 hello", "35 hello"))
regmatches(df$B, gregexpr("^\\D*(?=\\d)", df$B, perl=TRUE))
# [[1]]
# character(0)
# [[2]]
# [1] "lala "
# [[3]]
# [1] "number and "
# [[4]]
# [1] "face soap "
# [[5]]
# [1] ""
```

If you aren't familiar with regexes:

- `^`: beginning of string
- `\\D*` zero or more non-digits, analogous to `[^0-9]*`
- `(?=\\d)` means "look ahead for a digit but do not include it in the returned pattern" (a good ref for lookahead: https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html); this is a perl-extension to the regular expression, ergo the `perl=TRUE`

This produces a 0-length vector for the first. This is easy enough to deal with, perhaps with a quick helper function:

```
replace_len0 <- function(x, replace=NA) `[<-`(x, lengths(x) < 1, replace)
unlist(replace_len0(regmatches(df$B, gregexpr("^\\D*(?=\\d)", df$B, perl=TRUE)), ""))
# [1] ""            "lala "       "number and " "face soap "  ""
```

(I set the default replacement to `NA` because in my mind it is a difference between *"there is an empty string `""` before the first number"* and *"there is no number"*. Over to you.)

That can easily be assigned to `df$C` as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Another method using `extract` from `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  extract(B, "C", "^([a-z\\s]+)\\d", remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(C = replace(C, is.na(C), ""))
```

**Output:**

```
      A                   B           C
1  Alex                 but            
2 likes          lala 54 hi       lala 
3 a lot number and 33 hello number and 
4    of  face soap 34 hello  face soap 
5  food            35 hello
```